# AWS Lambda Unable to import module 'demo': cannot import name 'windll'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

Need a little help on aws lambda if ya'll came across this issue with deployment package uploading in aws lambda.

Regards,
xxSoumya----

[find snippet of issue ] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QeGe.png

Comment: Does your deployment package have the module demo in it?  What does your deployment package content look like?

Comment: yeah i've already zipped demo and contents in it are demo.py file , pandas, numpy, pytz libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment package structure should be something like this,

```
main.py  <---------- lambda entry/handler file
           (can be name anything, just config your aws lambda to use it)
demo.py
mylib/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  bar.py
numpy/
  ...
pandas/
  ...
```

If demo.py is in a another folder from where your main lambda handler file is locate, then you will need to put a "__init__".py in that folder.

```
main.py  <---------- lambda entry/handler file
mylib/
  __init__.py
  demo.py
  foo.py
  bar.py
numpy/
  ...
pandas/
  ...

Now in main, you will need to do, from mylib.demo import .....
```